# Error when trying to make a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to use `<canvas>` to construct a grid. Please note - the code below is not my code and I remember finding it on stack overflow somewhere:

Here is my error:

> Cannot call method 'getContext' of undefined

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>  
    <style type="text/css">

        body {
        background: lightblue;
    }

    canvas {
        background: #fff;
        margin: 20px;
    }
        </style>

<!-- JQ Lib -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

          //grid width and height
    var bw = 400;
    var bh = 400;
    //padding around grid
    var p = 10;
    //size of canvas
    var cw = bw + (p*2) + 1;
    var ch = bh + (p*2) + 1;

    var canvas = $('#canvas').attr({width: cw, height: ch}).appendTo('body');
var context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

    function drawBoard(){
        for (var x = 0; x <= bw; x += 40) {
            context.moveTo(0.5 + x + p, p);
            context.lineTo(0.5 + x + p, bh + p);
        }


        for (var x = 0; x <= bh; x += 40) {
            context.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x + p);
            context.lineTo(bw + p, 0.5 + x + p);
        }

        context.strokeStyle = "black";
        context.stroke();
    }

    drawBoard();
          </script>

        </head>


        <body>

        <canvas id="canvas">    </canvas>


        </body>
    </html>
```

The error is originating on this line:

```
 var canvas = $('#canvas').attr({width: cw, height: ch}).appendTo('body');
```

I have tried many different ways of doing this, but I keep getting the above error. Am I just making a mindless mistake here?

Comment: That code uses jQuery. If you aren't linking to that library you'll have to rewrite that line.

Comment: Have you definitely got a jQuery JS file included in your page?

Comment: Let me update my code with the JQ libraries through google, and the "new" error.

Comment: By the time you execute `$('#canvas')`, the element does not exist yet. Any code that accesses DOM elements has to be exectued after the corresponding element was created. Also, there is no need to include jQuery twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined `$`, which is a common (but [meaningless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting)) variable name used by a variety of different libraries including Protoype.js, Mootools and jQuery.

That syntax looks like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) so you will need to include the script for that library or rewrite it using built-in functions.

Comment: I was originally including the jQuery libraries, and it was just throwing other errors.

Comment: And now you have a completely different question. Please express it as such instead of changing the original question in such a way that invalidates this answer (or would do if the editing was complete instead of half done and thus not making a lot of sense).